# Find the total number of squares

Tags: combinatorics

**Q** Let $A_1, A_2, A_3,\ldots, A_{12}$ be the vertices of a regular dodecagon. Find the number of distinct squares in the plane of the dodecagon that has at least two vertices in the set $\{A_1, A_2, A_3,\ldots, A_{12}\}$.

I started by choosing $2$ vertices at a time and that is,

$$ {12 \choose 2} = 66 $$

then I multiplied it by $3$ because there were $3$ possibilities with it,
(1) that $2$ vertices can be diagonals.
($2$ and $3$) if vertices with any $2$ $A_i$ are consecutive in that Square then the square can be upwards or downwards.
$$ 66 * 3 = 198 $$

But, there were some duplicate squares like all the vertices of the square coincide with any $4$ vertices of a dodecagon. so I subtracted $3$. but still I didn't get the answer. The actual answer is $183$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the 3 squares that shares 4 vertices with the dodecagon is counted 6 times. So you need to subtract 5 of them. This gives
$$
198 - 5\cdot 3 = 183
$$

Comment: To be complete, we also need to show that no square shares exactly 3 vertices with the dodecagon, as those would have been counted 3 times each, and thus would have to be subtracted twice. But if a square shares 3 vertices with the dodecagon, a $90^\circ$ rotation about the center of the dodecagon doesn't change the figure at all, which shows that it also shares the fourth.